# Why the roster isn't added on both the sides?

Tags: java, smack

`user-a` sends a subscription request to `user-b`. Subscription mode has been set to `accept_all`. Also, *packet listener* has been registered for both the users.

When `user-a` sends a request to `user-b` this method is called :

```
    private void searchUser(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                            
        try {
            String userToSearch = jTextField1.getText(); 
                if(!xmppParamInit) {
                    initUXmppP();
                    xmppParamInit = true;
                }
                Presence subscribe = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribe);
                userToSearch += "@localhost";
                subscribe.setTo(userToSearch);
                ofConnection.sendPacket(subscribe); // Send the 'subscribe' packet
        }catch(Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Prior to this method, following are called :

```
private void startPLThread() { // start packet-listener-thread
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startPL();
        }
    };
    new Thread(r,"packet listener thread").start();
}

private void startPL() {
    PacketListener pListener = new PacketListener() {
        @Override
        public void processPacket(Packet packet) {System.out.println("Inside process packet");
            if(packet instanceof Presence) {
                Presence presence = (Presence) packet;
                Presence subscription = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribe);
                subscription.setTo(presence.getFrom());
                System.out.println("presence.getFrom : " + presence.getFrom());
                ofConnection.sendPacket(subscription);
            }
        }
    };

    PacketFilter pFilter = new PacketFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(Packet packet) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    ofConnection.addPacketListener(pListener, pFilter);
}
```

The problem is `user-a` can see `user-b` in his roster but `user-b` cannot see `user-a` in its roster. I do not understand the reason for this. What could be the problem ?

Subscription mode has been set to `accept_all` in this method that is called from within *search user* :

```
private void initUXmppP() { // Initialize user-xmpp-parameters
    Roster roster = ofConnection.getRoster();
    roster.setSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.accept_all);
}
```

*It is a GUI application and I tried keeping both the users online*

Comment: is the Presence packet received by user-b (or in other words, is processPacket called and is user-b sending a subcribe to user-a)?

Comment: @MarcVanDaele No. It is called as a routine.When `user-a` sends a packet to `user-b` _process packet_ is not called immediately. And when called the statement inside _process packet_ `if(packet instanceof Presence)` doesn't evaluate to true.

Comment: @MarcVanDaele but interesting thing is..after a while `if` statement evaluate to true for `user-a` which says that packet is received from `user-b`

Comment: @MarcVanDaele `user-b` sends subscribe to `user-a` as written inside the method `process packet`

Comment: Spawning a new thread in startPLThread() seems unnecessary, so is a packet filter that accepts all packets.

Comment: @Flow Does it hamper the whole process ?

Comment: Removing the thread and the filter will make the code more readable but won't fix your issue (imo). Can you change your logging inside the processPacket to System.out.println("Inside process packet "+packet)?  Then you can see which type of packet is received by user-b after user-a subscribes.  Make sure that you create two new users everytime you test this, otherwise previous subscriptions can interfere.

Comment: @MarcVanDaele It outputs in the object form..What do I infer from it ?

Comment: can't you infer the type (class) of the packet? You are expecting a packet of class Presence and apparently something else comes in.

Comment: @MarcVanDaele If `user-a` sends a request to `user-b`...`process packet` of `user-a` is invoked immediately and it prints `Inside process packet org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.RosterPacket@ad1af29` and then keeps printing `Inside process packet error`...process packet of `user-b` in routine prints `Inside process packet org.jivesoftware.smack.util.PacketParserUtils$2@4d7d88e8`

Comment: @MarcVanDaele What is happening ?

Comment: No idea. I would suggest to trace the actual packets that are being sent between user-a and user-b. In Smack, you can set     XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true; as  the first instruction and it'll show the enhanced debugger.  In there you can see which packets are sent and received.  Maybe that give more insight (see http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-networking-tutorials/551-how-write-simple-xmpp-jabber-client-using-smack-api.html for an example how the enhanced debugger looks like)

Comment: @MarcVanDaele nothing gets printed when I have placed the statement `XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true` just before the `connect` statement

Comment: it should be the first statememt in your application and it opens an additional window (see link in previous comment).